# Adding categories to pins in One Month Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, associations, categories

I have been working on  scaffold category for pins on a rails app for a while now. I have managed to assign a category to each new pin successfully, but how do I set it up so that when I go look at a certain specific category (ie. "cars"), it will automatically render all the pins in that "cars" category?

I have tried the codes similar to rendering pins of a specific user (ie. "user/1">, but that didn't work for categories, so how should I do it? Any help will be appreciated.

Here are my codes

```
view.categories.show.html.erb

<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>
  <b>Category</b>
 <%= @category.name %>
</h1>

<div id="pins">
  <%= render @pins %>
</div>

<%= will_paginate @pins %>
It returns the below

ArgumentError in Categories#show

Showing /Users/mattbook/code/starsworthy/app/views/categories/show.html.erb where line #9 raised:

'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object that returns a valid partial path.
```

Extracted source (around line #9):

Should I generate a partial like _pin.html.erb? how should I a approach that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're question is not so clear, but I can suggest the following:

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category # Add category_id in pins table
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pins
end
```

So to get all the pins of the bike category you can do this:

```
Category.where(name: "bike").first.pins
```

or:

```
Category.find_by_name("bike").pins
```

Comment: sorry I am such a newbie, but I can see your answer is where the two models are associated, and it's just only 1 little part of the whole setup process. I would like to understand the whole process of setting this category up, cuz I have searched and gone through several railscasts without much progress. Many thanks

Comment: hope you have basic conecept of migration and asociation if not please go through http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html and http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html and http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html...

Comment: @MatthewW. What exactly do you mean by setting this whole category up? What do you want to be able to do? That's very unclear.

Comment: Well, I have searched around. There are some who recommend adding pins to a Category through categorizations and others without categorizations. So I've tried both of the recommendations and followed their instructions without much success, I guess and somewhere in the middle I got all confused.

Comment: @MatthewW. first try without categorizations. Without is easier. Once you get it working you can have a look at polymorphic relationships (categorizations), but that's a somewhat advanced subject for a beginner.

Comment: @Mischa Thanks Mischa. Actually I think I have no problem setting up the associations between Pins and Categories. But I don't know how to set it up so that users can select a category when posting a pin. Also how  to set it up so that, when a specific category ie."Restaurants"or "Clubs" is looked up, all the pins in those categories will show up.